# Monitoring Postgres with Zabbix (Both of them are dockerized)

Tags: postgresql, docker, zabbix

I have installed Zabbix from this [link](https://medium.com/jungletronics/zabbix-docker-containers-rocks-421524826f5e) and Postgres DB, both on docker on Ubuntu 20.04. How to monitor Postgres with Zabbix in this situation?

Comment: did you already follow https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/postgresql?at=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F5.0 ?

Comment: This link is for ordinary Zabbix not a dockerized one. The problem is I installed Zabbix on docker.

Comment: you have a network issue then, not a Zabbix issue

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom Zabbix-agent docker image with psql inside

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).